# button with onClick={refreshPage}

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, page-refresh

*Using React, Firestore V9*
I have an addDoc function that add user's input to firestore collection, but user needs to refresh the page to see his input. How can I reprogramm my code to immediately refresh the page after user clicks on submit button?
Code:

```
<input placeholder='firestore' onChange={ (event) => {
          setAnswer(event.target.value);
            
        }}/> 
<button onClick={createUser}>send to firestore</button>
```

What about adding to button an second onClick={refreshPage}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.then` to make sure it reloads after `addDoc` is done adding the document to firestore

```
addDoc() // your document insert logic
.then(()=>{
window.location.reload() //here comes your reload logic
})
.catch((err)=>{
console.log(err)
})
```